# Lazy loading controller error "[ng:areq] Argument 'aboutCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading

I am using require js in my project to load controllers on demand, I am getting "[ng:areq] Argument 'aboutCtrl' is not a function, got undefined" exception while invoking "aboutCtrl", i have configured "$controllerProvider" to register controller and i see the respective file has been downloaded by require js. I am posting my code as follows

> Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS SPA</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-include="'views/shared/_header.html'"></div>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

> main.js

```js
require.config({
    baseurl: '/scripts/',
    paths: {
        'angular': 'libs/angular',        
        'ui-router': 'libs/angular-ui-router',
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery-1.10.2',
        'bootstrap': 'libs/bootstrap',        
        'homeCtrl': "controllers/homeCtrl"        
    },
    shim: {        
        'ui-router': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
    deps: ['app']
});

require(["app","bootstrap","homeCtrl"],function (app) {        
        app.init();
});
```

> app.js

```js
define(['ui-router'], function () {

    var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router']);        

    app.config(['$controllerProvider', function ($controllerProvider) {
        app.registerController = $controllerProvider.register;
    } ]);

    app.init = function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    };

    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: 'views/home/home.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'                
            })
        .state("about", {
            url: "/about",
            templateUrl: 'views/account/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl',
            resolve: {
                load: ['$q', function ($q) {
                    var defered = $q.defer();
                    require(['../scripts/controllers/aboutCtrl'], function () {
                        defered.resolve();
                    });
                    return defered.promise;
                } ]
            }
        });
    });
    return app;
});
```

> homeCtrl.js

```js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller("homeCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.Message = "About Us";  
    });
});
```

> aboutCtrl.js

```js
define(['app'], function (app) {
    app.controller("aboutCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.Message = "About Us";        
    });
});
```

**Error Details**
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'aboutCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

[image]

Comment: You didn't include aboutCtrl in require.

Comment: I want to load aboutCtrl on demand hence did not include it